Multiple endpoints for one IP address in SentinelOne
I have multiple endpoints for the same pc in sentinel. The pc was restarted a few times and sentinelOne was installed each time which led to multiple endpoints in the management console.
How do I remove the extra ones without messing up the correct endpoint?
I didn’t want to try and uninstall from the useless endpoints in fear that it will uninstall from the correct endpoint.
